# How to check IPv6 address of an IPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipv6, ios9.3

I have setup a IPv6 nat64 environment based on apple recommendations

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html,

however when i connect my iphone 6 to this network i am not able to see the ipv6 address in Wifi network settings to which i am connected. Please help me to get the ipv6 address of iphone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The iPhone tool of Hurricane Electric is very useful to check your network settings and connectivity:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/he.net-network-tools/id858241710

The built-in user interface from Apple doesn't show IPv6 information unfortunately.

Comment: thanks for info that interface doesnt show IPv6 info!